# How can I get a non-blocking SSL Socket in Asyncio?

Tags: python-asyncio

So, I can pretty easily create an `SSLSocket` in asyncio:

```
# Create a Socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setblocking(False)

# Connect
await loop.sock_connect(sock, host_address)  # type: ignore

# Create an SSL Context
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=PROXY_CA_BUNDLE)
...

# Wrap the SSL Context Around the Socket
def do_handshake(loop, sock, waiter):
    sock_fd = sock.fileno()
    try:
        sock.do_handshake()
    except ssl.SSLWantReadError:
        loop.remove_reader(sock_fd)
        loop.add_reader(sock_fd, do_handshake,
                        loop, sock, waiter)
        return
    except ssl.SSLWantWriteError:
        loop.remove_writer(sock_fd)
        loop.add_writer(sock_fd, do_handshake,
                        loop, sock, waiter)
        return

    loop.remove_reader(sock_fd)
    loop.remove_writer(sock_fd)
    waiter.set_result(None)

 waiter = loop.create_future()
 do_handshake(loop, sslconn, waiter)
 await waiter
```

The problem is that an SSLSocket [breaks the non-blocking interface](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-nonblocking) of the original socket library, so it is no longer compatible with other asyncio methods like `asyncio.sock_sendall`.  Is there a way to instead wrap a socket and have it still respect the original socket interface?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the low-level `loop.remove_reader()` and `loop.add_reader()` API instead of the streams API? For example, [`loop.create_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_connection) supports creating SSL connections - can you use that?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the streams API; I need to pass the socket into a Cython application which expects a default python Socket.

Comment: Does the Cython application expect a blocking or a non-blocking socket? Also, if the socket is expected by the application, why connect it to the asyncio event loop at all?

Comment: Non-blocking socket (as above). Usecase is basically using asyncio to construct a proxy connection (HTTP), then need the raw socket for the cython protocol.

Comment: If the only problem is that asyncio doesn't work with the wrapped socket, then I'd call the high-level API and then obtain the socket it used. For example, subclass `SSLContext` and provide a [`wrap_socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket) impl that stores the `SSLSocket` created by `super().wrap_socket(...)` to a place of your choosing. After calling [`open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) with `ssl=<your context>` and setting up the proxy, you could extract the `SSLSocket` and pass it to Cython.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem either; the SSLSocket implementation breaks the Cython application too.